# Calculate size of tableviewcell with a few labels

Tags: ios, uitableview, row-height, heightforrowatindexpath

So I have a UITableViewCell that I would like to calculate the size of to return in

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

but this cell has a few `UILabels` inside.

I could go and calculate all the heights using `sizeWithAttributes`, but this would give me quite some work to do this for all my cells (I have quite a few different cells), so I am looking for a way to have my cells calculate their own height.

I have tried to use `systemSizeFittingSize` method, but that fails because it only accounts for one row (apparently).

What can I do? I have been looking for an answer to this question for a long time and none of the answers seem to be working all the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18746929/4151918

Comment: what do you want exactly , do you want your label font need to fit depend upon the height ? ,if it is your problem then i have a solution